How do I prove that $a_n \to 0, b_n \to 0 \to a_n + b_n \rightarrow 0$ without pre-established limit rules?
I've been at this for several hours now and I'm unsure if I'm overthinking it or missing something obvious For the more general case, $a_n \to a, b_n \to b \implies a_n + b_n \to a + b$. I would formulate the following proof:
Given any $\epsilon > 0$, choose an integer $N > 0$ such that $|a_n - a| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|b_n - b| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ both hold for all $n > N$.
We would like to show that $\lim{(a_n + b_n)} = a + b$, that is, for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find some $N$ such that $|a_n + b_n - (a + b)| < \epsilon$ whenever $n > N$. We can show this in the following way: $|a_n + b_n - (a + b)| = |(a_n - a) + (b_n - b)| \leq |a_n - a| + |b_n - b| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} + \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$.
(Technically, we should have $N = \max\lbrace N_1, N_2, N_3 \rbrace$. I hope that it's clear enough from the context what $N_1$, $N_2$ and $N_3$ are.) We could instead also have said—perhaps this would be a circular argument—that $\lim{(a_n + b_n)} = \lim{a_n} + \lim{b_n} = a + b$.
In this particular case, I do not want to assume that this limit rule holds, nor do I want to prove the limit in the case $a = b = 0$ by "knowing" the limit and then showing that it is indeed true. What I would like to do is something like this:
Let $\lim{a_n} = 0$, let $\lim{b_n} = 0$ and let $\lim{(a_n + b_n)} = L$ for some $L \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, and choose $N > 0$ so that
$\begin{align}|a_n| &< \frac{\epsilon}{2}&\\|b_n| &< \frac{\epsilon}{2}&\\|a_n + b_n - L| &< \epsilon &\end{align}$ all hold for all $n > N$.
Here is where I get stuck. I want to do... something... that leads to us concluding that $L = 0$ (for example, assume that $L > 0$ and reach a contradiction). I've this vague idea of choosing $\epsilon < L$ and do something with that, but I've no idea what. I do have the following, which I don't know exactly what to do with:
$|a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|b_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ implies that $|a_n| + |b_n| < \epsilon$. Since $|a_n| + |b_n| \geq |a_n + b_n|$, it holds that $|a_n + b_n| < \epsilon$.
Since we can now make $|a_n + b_n|$ arbitrarily small, I want to conclude that $L = 0$ but somehow I'm not convinced. (Would I need to invoke the uniqueness of limits here? I've proven this, so I would be okay with using this fact.)
Alternatively, we could subtract $|a_n + b_n| < \epsilon$ from $|a_n + b_n - L| < \epsilon$ which would give us
$|a_n + b_n - L| - |a_n + b_n| < 0 \Rightarrow |a_n + b_n - L| < |a_n + b_n| < \epsilon$, but also if we switch the subtractions, we get instead $|a_n + b_n | < |a_n + b_n - L|$.
These strict inequalities can't both be true which, again, suggests that $L = 0$ but I am somehow still not fully convinced.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated, especially such that nudge towards some interesting (not necessarily correct) path.

If $3<4$ and $2<4$, then it does not follow that $3-2<4-4$ :-); this about the part you write "Alternatively, we could subtract ...".

I'm confused. Your first proof is perfectly fine, but then you say you don't want to use it, then you present an almost complete second proof of the same fact specialized to 0, which you then discard to push on towards a third proof and finally get stuck, still unconvinced. At this point you really should tell us why you're unconvinced, above anything else :)

In your first proof, you can have $n > N=\max(N_1,N_2)$, but I suspect you are unlikely to be able to avoid something equivalent to that.

Hint: $\lvert L \rvert=\lvert (a_n+b_n)- (a_n+b_n-L) \rvert\leq \lvert a_n+b_n \rvert + \lvert a_n+b_n-L\rvert$. So if you have that $\lvert a_n+b_n \rvert$ and $\lvert a_n+b_n - L \rvert$ can be arbitrarily small, then the same is true for $\lvert L \rvert$, which implies $L=0$. You can work similarly in the general case.

@BenSteffan For the first, general proof, we are already given the fact and are asked to verify it. In the second proof, I do show that we can make $|a_n - b_n|$ arbitrarily small. At least to me, it does not, however, explicitly make clear that $|a_n + b_n - L| < \epsilon$ implies that $L = 0$. I think you'd need to prove uniqueness of limits in this case, no?
I'm not sure which counts as the "third proof". My apologies for my confusion!

@Math-fun Haha! I suspected that my subtraction of inequalities was not correct. Thank you for clarifying this! :)

Your first proof if in fact completely right, so you don't need to do anything else. What I understand from your question is that you want to find the limit of $a_n+b_n$ assuming you don't know what the answer might be, or even trying to 'guess' it by showing that $a+b$ works. So one approach might be:
Given $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that $\lvert a_n - a\rvert<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $\lvert b_n - b\rvert<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for every $n\geq N$. This implies that
$$a-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}< a_n < a + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
and
$$b-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}< b_n < b + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
Therefore, adding these inequalities in order to get a bound for $a_n+b_n$, we have
$$a+b-\varepsilon< a_n+b_n < a+b+\varepsilon.$$
This is the same to say $\lvert a_n+b_n-(a+b)\rvert<\varepsilon$, so by the definition of limit, $a_n+b_n\rightarrow a+b$.
I hope this proof seems more natural to you, but note that, in fact, it's essentialy the same as the first one you gave.

This is exactly right. I wanted to find a proof that made no any assumptions about the limit a priori. I suppose another way of formulating my question would've been: "Given two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ that both converge to $0$, what can we say about the limit of the sequence $a_n + b_n$?".
Your proof makes no assumption about the limit, but instead "finds" it by "investigating" $a_n$ and $b_n$. Thank you!
